# Request-response model over sockets/websockets

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, timeout

This is a request-response model over sockets/websockets (like HTTP) where you technically match request id to response id and return the response. In addition to that, there is timeout in case that message is never matched. It does its job but the implementation is not disposing the `CancellationTokenSource` and `TaskCompletionSource`. It may even be done in a better way, so here is why I want a code review.

### Example usage

```cs
var requestManager = new RequestManager();
var input = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Test { Message = "Hello World" });

var pending = requestManager.AddPendingRequest(x =>
{
    var text = x.Deserialize<Test>();
    return text?.Message == "Hello World";
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

await Task.Delay(4000);

var jsonElement = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(input);

if (requestManager.TryMatchRequest(jsonElement))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}

public class Test
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

### Code to review

````cs
public class PendingRequest
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public PendingRequest(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Handler = handler;
        Event = new AsyncResetEvent(false, false);
        Timeout = timeout;

        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        _cts.Token.Register(Fail, false);
    }

    public Func<JsonElement, bool> Handler { get; }
    public JsonElement? Result { get; private set; }
    public bool Completed { get; private set; }
    public AsyncResetEvent Event { get; }
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; }

    public bool CheckData(JsonElement data)
    {
        if (Handler(data))
        {
            Result = data;
            Completed = true;
            Event.Set();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Fail()
    {
        Completed = true;
        Event.Set();
    }
}

public class RequestManager
{
    private readonly IList<PendingRequest> _pendingRequests = new List<PendingRequest>();

    public PendingRequest AddPendingRequest(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var pending = new PendingRequest(handler, timeout);

        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            _pendingRequests.Add(pending);
        }

        return pending;
    }

    public void FailAllPendingRequests()
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            foreach (var pendingRequest in _pendingRequests.ToList())
            {
                pendingRequest.Fail();
                _pendingRequests.Remove(pendingRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<PendingRequest> GetAllPendingRequests()
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            return _pendingRequests;
        }
    }

    public bool TryMatchRequest(JsonElement tokenData)
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            foreach (var request in _pendingRequests)
            {
                if (!request.CheckData(tokenData))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                _pendingRequests.Remove(request);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void RemoveTimedOutRequests()
    {
        PendingRequest[] requests;
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            requests = _pendingRequests.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var request in requests.Where(r => r.Completed))
        {
            lock (_pendingRequests)
            {
                _pendingRequests.Remove(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Async auto reset based on Stephen Toub`s implementation
///     https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/
/// </summary>
public sealed class AsyncResetEvent : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Task<bool> Completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _waits = new();
    private readonly bool _reset;
    private bool _signaled;

    /// <summary>
    ///     New AsyncResetEvent
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initialState"></param>
    /// <param name="reset"></param>
    public AsyncResetEvent(bool initialState = false, bool reset = true)
    {
        _signaled = initialState;
        _reset = reset;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _waits.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Wait for the AutoResetEvent to be set
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (_signaled)
            {
                if (_reset)
                {
                    _signaled = false;
                }

                return Completed;
            }

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
            if (timeout != null)
            {
                var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout.Value);
                cancellationSource.Token.Register(() =>
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(false);
                }, false);
            }

            _waits.Enqueue(tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Signal a waiter
    /// </summary>
    public void Set()
    {
        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (!_reset)
            {
                // Act as ManualResetEvent. Once set keep it signaled and signal everyone who is waiting
                _signaled = true;
                while (_waits.Count > 0)
                {
                    var toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
                    toRelease.TrySetResult(true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Act as AutoResetEvent. When set signal 1 waiter
                if (_waits.Count > 0)
                {
                    var toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
                    toRelease.TrySetResult(true);
                }
                else if (!_signaled)
                {
                    _signaled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I think no one is brave enough here to review Stephen Toub's code :P That's why I would suggest to mention it in the question but remove his work from the shared code fragment.

Comment: True^ It's a bit modified tho https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent (the part with the CancellationTokenSource)

Comment: Then IMHO it would make sense to have a separate review for that... But that's my opinion

Comment: Tbh, I don't mind if anything else is used instead, e.g. Nito.AsyncEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `PendingRequest`

#### Public interface

I would suggest to try to minimize the public surface of this class. I think only `Completed` and `Result` should be exposed as properties, others could remain as private fields.

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationSignal;
private readonly Func<JsonElement, bool> _handler;
private readonly AsyncResetEvent _completionSignal = new(false, false);
  
public JsonElement? Result { get; private set; }
public bool Completed { get; private set; }
```

As in the above example, I would suggest to use better naming than `_cts` and `Event`.

#### Guard expression vs Early exit

In the `CheckData` it might make sense to use an early exit to streamline the code

```
if (!_handler(data))
    return false;
        
Result = data;
Completed = true;
_completionSignal.Set();
return true;
```

#### Code duplication

These two lines are executed both inside the `CheckData` and in the `Fail`

```
Completed = true;
_completionSignal.Set();
```

Depending on the use case I might rename the `Fail` to `CompleteImmediately`/`CompleteNow` and use it inside the `CheckData` OR extract that code and use it multiple places

---

For the sake of completeness here is the entire class

```
public class PendingRequest
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationSignal;
    private readonly Func<JsonElement, bool> _handler;
    private readonly AsyncResetEvent _completionSignal = new(false, false);
  
    public JsonElement? Result { get; private set; }
    public bool Completed { get; private set; }

    public PendingRequest(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _cancellationSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        _cancellationSignal.Token.Register(CompleteNow, false);
    }

    public bool CheckData(JsonElement data)
    {
        if (!_handler(data))
            return false;
        
        Result = data;
        CompleteNow();
        return true;
    }

    public void Fail() => CompleteNow();

    private void CompleteNow()
    {
        Completed = true;
        _completionSignal.Set();
    }
}
```

### `RequestManager`

#### Method naming

IMHO adding everywhere `Request` or `PendingRequest` as a method suffix is unnecessary. From the class name and from the methods' parameters it should clear what we are talking about.

#### Thread-safe collection vs lock

If possible I would suggest to use one of the [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection) because they are thread-safe for sure and they might utilize lock-free algorithms.

Because you need to add and remove items from the collection I would suggest to use `ConcurrentDictionary`. (*`ConcurrentBag` might be tempting at the first glance, but it [does not really support arbitrary item removal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.trytake?view=net-7.0).*)

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, PendingRequest> _requests = new();
```

I've removed `readonly`, because we will set a new value for it in multiple methods.

#### `Add`

```
public PendingRequest Add(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var pending = new PendingRequest(handler, timeout);
    _requests.TryAdd(Guid.NewGuid(), pending);
    return pending;
}
```

The key does not matter here, we just need to make sure that it is unique.

#### `FailAll` / `CompleteAllNow`

```
public void FailAll()
{
    foreach (var (_ ,pendingRequest) in _requests)
        pendingRequest.Fail();
        
    _requests = new();
}
```

First we complete all requests right away then we empty the `_requests` collection.

#### `GetAll`

```
public IList<PendingRequest> GetAll()
    => _requests.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
```

Because we use a `Dictionary` that's why we need to transform the `KeyValuePair` elements.

#### `TryMatch`

If my understanding is correct then you want to remove the first match (not all the matches)

```
public bool TryMatch(JsonElement tokenData)
{
    var request = _requests.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Value.CheckData(tokenData));
    if (request.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<Guid, int>)))
        return false;

    return _requests.TryRemove(request);
}
```

Here you can't use the `== default` or `is default` for the `KeyValuePair` struct.

#### `RemoveTimedOut`

```
public void RemoveTimedOut()
{
    var completed = _requests.Where(r => r.Value.Completed);
    _requests = new(_requests.Except(completed));
}
```

Here we create a new collection without those requests which are already completed.

---

For the sake of completeness here is the entire class

```
public class RequestManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, PendingRequest> _requests = new();

    public PendingRequest Add(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var pending = new PendingRequest(handler, timeout);
        _requests.TryAdd(Guid.NewGuid(), pending);
        return pending;
    }

    public void FailAll()
    {
        foreach (var (_ ,pendingRequest) in _requests)
            pendingRequest.Fail();
        
        _requests = new();
    }

    public IList<PendingRequest> GetAll()
        => _requests.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList();

    public bool TryMatch(JsonElement tokenData)
    {
        var request = _requests.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Value.CheckData(tokenData));
        if (request.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<Guid, int>)))
            return false;

        return _requests.TryRemove(request);
    }

    public void RemoveTimedOut()
    {
        var completed = _requests.Where(r => r.Value.Completed);
        _requests = new(_requests.Except(completed));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the descriptive answer! Where do you think is alright to dispose the CancellationTokenSource instance?

Comment: @nop I think inside the `CompleteNow` it would make sense for me.

Comment: Thank you very much once again! ^^